# AWS Key Management Service Hashing along with encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kms

During the data in transit across cross accounts we want to ensure the data is hashed along with encryption to ensure data received after decryption is not tampered. Please suggest any mechanisms for the same.

Few scenarios I am concerned are:

1. Source: Cloudwatch logs in Account  A  Destination: Kinesis Stream in Account B
2. Cross Account S3 Replication

Comment: I'm not sure what is the context of the question. Under the encryption do you mean the default AWS encryption with KMS? (storage, etc..)

Comment: I meant encryption with customer managed keys

Comment: Any "encryption in rest" directly with KMS is using the AES-GCM mode, which already includes the authentication tag (AWS doesn't disclose much about the details, but it was mentioned in one of their documetation, I'm unable to find it back atm).